# Efficiency in for loop

Tags: java

How could the following code snippet be optimized? I'm creating space objects to be filled in a 2D array to act as a chess board and am using this to create a more standard naming system.

```
String name = null;
    for(int r = 7; r > -1; r--)
        for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
        {
            if(c == 0)
                name = "A";
            else if(c == 1)
                name = "B";
            else if(c == 2)
                name = "C";
            else if(c == 3)
                name = "D";
            else if(c == 4)
                name = "E";
            else if(c == 5)
                name = "F";
            else if(c == 6)
                name = "G";
            else
                name = "H";
```

Comment: Optimize for readability with a switch rather than the it/else construct

Comment: You can do `'A'+c` but it results in a `char` rather than a `String`. I don't know whether `Character.toString('A'+c);` is faster than loading a string literal.

Comment: You can also do `for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'H'; c++) {name = Character.toString(c); }` ;-)

Comment: BTW: to ask better questions you may provide a **working** code snippet, so that other users may execute and debug it. You could also specify which kind of optimization you would like to achive: execution speed, readability, ...

Comment: You might be able to modify your data structure to use a Map instead of an Array. Then you'd have lookup times of O(1) instead of O(n²).

Comment: @sissonb array access are O(1), therefore 2D array access are also O(1)

Comment: @AlexvanVliet I'm talking about the lookup using that nested for loop. Maybe the data structure could look something like this. `{"a1":"a", "a2":"a"}`. Then the lookup is simple. `Map.get("a1")` vs `for(...){for(...){...}}`

Comment: @sissonb Oh okay I see, then it depends of the code that we don't see (which could therefore be useful for further improvement)

Answer (score 3):

```
final static char[] letters = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' };
      :
for (int c=0; c<8; c++) {
    name = letters[c];
      :
```

This has name as a `char` - does it really need to be a String?  If so, make the obvious changes. Define letters as a String[] rather than runtime conversion from char-to-String if you are concerned with efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over characters and change it to a string like this :

```
for (int r=7; r >= 0; r--) {
    for (char c='A'; c <= 'H'; c++) {
        name = c + "";
```

Comment: I'd guess, though, that he also will need the column as an integer, so will also need a char-to-int conversion. For my taste, that's less clear than having both loops be based on the integer row/column numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You never finished your `for` loops, but here is one way to optimize what you have showed us so far:

```
String name = null;
String letters = "ABCDEFGH";

for (int r=7; r >= 0; r--) {
    for (int c=0; c < 8; c++) {
        name = letters.charAt(c) + "";

        // the rest of your logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII code for 'A' is 65 and for 'H' is 72. Then, you can do something like this

```
for (int r = 7; r > -1; r--) {
    for(int c = 65; c < 73; c++) {
        name = Character.toString((char) c);
        //or
        name = "" + (char) c;
    }
}
```